# Need help switching from nVidia to AMD Gpu

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, gpu-driver, amdgpu

I've upgraded my gpu from geforce 8500gt to amd rx580, and i cant log into system (gives me a message about unsigned key or wrongly signed key). I think this is drivers matter, so how can i uninstall the nvidia ones and install the amd drivers?

Edit: forgot to add; my gpu gives video output but fans wont spin

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: I had an RX580 that did the exact same thing; couldn't get the fans to spin unless I booted into Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Nvidia drivers by

```
sudo apt purge 'nvidia.*'
```

AMD drivers are in-tree in modern Ubuntu releases. So there is no need to install drivers.

Comment: It sorta works. It now boots normally but it sometimes flickers, which is not so comfortable